# Flutter Bloc state change is not updated UI with get_it

Tags: flutter, bloc, service-locator

I've been building a login/authentication feature using a combination of this login tutorial and the resocoder clean architecture tutorials. It's 99% working perfectly, but it is not responding properly to the `LoginButton` being pressed.

For some reason when `LoginBloc` calls `AuthenticationBloc.add(loggedin())`, the AuthenticationBloc yields the `AuthenticationAuthenticated()` state just fine, but the `BlocBuilder` in Main.dart doesn't receive the state change. Even the `OnTransition` inside SimpleBlocDelegate is triggered when `AuthenticationAuthenticated` is yielded, but `BlocBuilder` does nothing.

`Main.dart` looks like this:

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/dependency_injector.dart' as di;
import 'package:flutter_app/features/login/presentation/pages/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'features/login/presentation/bloc/user_login_bloc.dart';
import 'features/login/presentation/bloc/user_login_events.dart';
import 'features/login/presentation/bloc/user_login_states.dart';

class SimpleBlocDelegate extends BlocDelegate {
  @override
  void onEvent(Bloc bloc, Object event) {
    print(event);
    super.onEvent(bloc, event);
  }

  @override
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {
    print(transition);
    super.onTransition(bloc, transition);
  }

  @override
  void onError(Bloc bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    print(error);
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
  }
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await di.init(); //Dependency Injection using get_it
  BlocSupervisor.delegate = SimpleBlocDelegate();
  runApp(
    BlocProvider<UserAuthenticationBloc>(
      create: (_) => sl<UserAuthenticationBloc>()..add(AppStarted()),
      child: App(),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  App({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BlocBuilder<UserAuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
            return Container(
              child: HomePage(); // THIS NEVER HAPPENS, even though AuthBloc yields the State
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
            return LoginScreen(); // THIS yeilds fine when AppStarted in passed on init.
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
            return LoadingIndicator();
          }
          return Scaffold(
            body: SplashPage();
          )
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can only think it has something to do with `get_it`. The Dependency Injection looks like this:

```
final sl = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> init() async {
  sl.registerFactory(
    () => UserAuthenticationBloc(
      getCachedUser: sl(),
    ),
  );

  sl.registerFactory(
    () => LoginBloc(authenticationBloc: sl(), getUserFromEmailAndPassword: sl()),
  );
...
}
```

and then in the widget tree for the `loginscreen` the `LoginBloc` gets created, so it is available to the login form.

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  LoginScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(
        create: (_) => sl<LoginBloc>(),
        child: LoginForm(), //login form
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

TWO EDITS: 
1. I changed `UserAuthenticationBloc` in the dependency-injection file from a factory to a lazysingleton... now it works. However, I heard that using singletons for classes with Streams can cause memory leaks?? I guess it means that `LoginBloc` is not talking to the same instance of `AuthBloc` that Main.dart is listening to? I've no idea how to ensure that without the singleton...

2. Code of UserAuthenticationBloc:

```
    class UserAuthenticationBloc extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
      final GetCachedUser getCachedUser;
      UserAuthenticationBloc({
        @required GetCachedUser getCachedUser,
      })  : assert(getCachedUser != null),
            getCachedUser = getCachedUser;

      @override
      AuthenticationState get initialState => AuthenticationUninitialized();

      @override
      Stream<AuthenticationState> mapEventToState(AuthenticationEvent event) async* {
        if (event is AppStarted) {
             yield AuthenticationUnauthenticated();
          }
        }

        if (event is LoggedIn) {
          yield AuthenticationAuthenticated(); //this fires.
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: can u share the code of `UserAuthenticationBloc`

Comment: @SanjaySharma Have added.

Comment: Does `AuthenticationState` inherit `Equatable` ?

Comment: @SanjaySharma Yes it does.

Comment: @GaryFrewin your edits were truly appreciated by me. I've looked around and can't find a straight answer to the question you had about memory leaks. Have you found out anything? If I find something I will get back to you.

Comment: @M-Solutions I never found any more information I'm afraid. I continued what I was doing and now have 5 blocs all set up this way in the app. Performance seems fine so far.

Comment: @GaryFrewin are you managed to get it working? I am having a similar issue, change registerFactory to registerLazySingleton solves the issue but if I clear the route and go to the page again, an exception throws "Cannot add new events after calling close occurred in bloc Instance of 'LoginBloc'"

Comment: @trinvh Hi. Once I changed the bloc class to a lazysingleton it started working. I've had no performance issues at all and don't fully understand it all so I left it at that. If I get performance issues, I'll take another look. However, I was also using equatable for my states. I stopped doing this as I read elsewhere it can interfere with a blocbuilder.

Comment: Hi, getit creates a new bloc every time it will requested because you registered it with registerFactory. So the loginbloc has another instance of the authbloc than the main Widget

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**EDIT**
Use bloc provided methods for dependency injection rather than get_it. Creating a singleton can be a issue as it won't be disposed automatically.`BlocProvider` handles and disposes the created bloc as mentioned in docs

> In most cases, BlocProvider should be used to create new blocs which will be made available to the rest of the subtree. In this case, since BlocProvider is responsible for creating the bloc, it will automatically handle closing the bloc.

And use `BlocProvider.value` to pass the value as suggested in bloc official [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocprovider).

```dart
BlocProvider(
  create: (BuildContext context) => BlocA(service1: sl<Service1>()),
  child: ChildA(),
);
```

This is how I use BlocProvider and get_it together. I use get_it for everything other than Bloc. And the parameters for bloc are provided by get_it's dependency injection.

If you want to use get_it, read TLDR; section.

**TLDR;**

Use `Singleton` only when necessary (`AuthenticationBloc`). And keep using `Factory` for all the other Blocs (`LoginBloc`, etc).

```
final sl = GetIt.instance;
final Environment _env = Environment();

Future<void> init() async {
  //! Core
  ..load some singletons

  //! Bloc
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => AuthenticationBloc(secureStorage: sl()));
  sl.registerFactory(() => LoginBloc(authenticationBloc: sl(), authService: sl()));
  sl.registerFactory(() => SignupBloc(authenticationBloc: sl(), authService: sl()));
}
```

**Concepts**

I use the same approach when using bloc. The most common case we encounter where we need to two blocs to communicate is AuthenticationBloc communicates to almost all the other blocs.

**Why `registerFactory` do not work. But `registerLazySingleton` does**

The definition by getit for `registerFactory`

> You have to pass a factory function func that returns an NEW instance of an implementation of T. Each time you call get() you will get a new instance returned

As per the get_it documentation. `registerFactory` generates a new instance of Bloc object every time we call the `sl<AuthenticationBloc>()` method.
Now when `LoginBloc` Constructor asks for a parameter and we pass `sl()` in our dependecy injection file, we are creating a new instance and passing it to our `LoginBloc`. Hence the `AuthenticationBloc` instance which is in use throughout our app is not equal to the `AuthenticationBloc` that we have provided to our `LoginBloc` constructor. And as a result your `AuthenticationBloc` won't listen to changes that are communicated by `LoginBloc` as it added event to some other instance of `AuthenticationBloc`.

`registerLazySingleton` is defined as

> You have to pass a factory function func that returns an instance of an implementation of T. Only the first time you call get() this factory function will be called to create a new instance.

And as explained above the simple solution would be to change the dependency injection from `registerFactory` to `registerLazySingleton`. By doing this you will be providing a single instance of `AuthenticationBloc` throughout the application. Hence events added to `AuthenticationBloc` from `LoginBloc` will start working.

**Proposed Solution**

There can be two solution. One is that is proposed in this question i.e. change every Bloc to `lazySingleton`. But it won't create new Bloc when needed. By using that method you will be using the same Bloc instance throughout the application. It is suitable for most the situations.

Another way is to make `Singleton` only when necessary (`AuthenticationBloc`). And keep using `Factory` for all the other Blocs (`LoginBloc`, etc).

**Authentication Bloc**

```
class AuthenticationBloc extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  final SecureStorage secureStorage;

  AuthenticationBloc({required this.secureStorage}) : super(AppInitial());

  @override
  Stream<AuthenticationState> mapEventToState(AuthenticationEvent event) async* {
    if (event is AppStarted) {
      AuthModel? authModel = await secureStorage.getAuthUser();
      if (authModel != null && authModel.jwtToken.isNotEmpty && authModel.userId.isNotEmpty) {
        yield AuthenticationUserKnown(authModel: authModel);
      } else {
        yield AuthenticationUserUnknown();
      }
    } else if (event is UserAuthenticated) {
      yield AuthenticationUserKnown(authModel: event.authModel);
    } else if (event is UserLoggedOut) {
      yield AuthenticationUserUnknown();
    }
  }
}
```

**Login Bloc**

```
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  LoginBloc({required this.authenticationBloc, required this.validationHelper, required this.authService})
      : super(LoginInitial());
  final AuthenticationBloc authenticationBloc;
  final AuthService authService;
  final ValidationHelper validationHelper;

  @override
  Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(LoginEvent event) async* {
    if (event is EmailAuthenticationRequested) {
      yield* _mapEmailAuthencationRequestedEventToState(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<LoginState> _mapEmailAuthencationRequestedEventToState(EmailAuthenticationRequested event) async* {
    yield AuthenticationInProgress();
    final authEither = await authService.loginWithEmail(email: event.email, password: event.password);

    yield authEither.fold(
      (failure) => LoginAuthenticationFailure(failureMessage: failure.errorMessage),
      (authModel) {
        authenticationBloc.add(UserAuthenticated(authModel: authModel));
        return LoginAuthenticationSuccess(authModel: authModel, authenticationMethod: AuthenticationMethod.EMAIL);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    authenticationBloc.close();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

**Dependency injector**

```
final sl = GetIt.instance;
final Environment _env = Environment();

Future<void> init() async {
  //! Core
  ..load some singletons

  //! Bloc
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => AuthenticationBloc(secureStorage: sl()));
  sl.registerFactory(() => LoginBloc(authenticationBloc: sl(), validationHelper: sl(), authService: sl()));
  sl.registerFactory(() => SignupBloc(validationHelper: sl(), authService: sl()));
}
```

Comment: You should make this a bloc post as it answers a lot of questions that I have not seen answered anywhere else.

Comment: sure sometime soon

Comment: I had the same dilemma and then I found out that you can actually avoid having blocs depending on blocs. You just need to wisely use Events and BlocBuilders/Consumers in the right places in your widgets. For instance, in OP's case, you don't need to pass `getCachedUser` to the bloc as long as you fire an event carrying the cached user as a parameter.

Comment: Yes now in the new pattern proposed by the author of Bloc Felix Angelov. We can use reactive repository to avoid bloc to bloc communication. By connecting blocs with [domain](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=connecting-blocs-through-domain) or [presentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=presentation-layer).

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same issue in my project. I'm using the same stack, and also when I add an Event from another bloc, the UI doesn't see any changes. The temporary solution I use - I pass context to that bloc using `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>`. So then UI and Bloc are using the same context. You can use it in your `LoginBloc`:

```
BlocProvider.of<UserAuthenticationBloc>(yourScaffoldKey.currentContext).add(LoggedIn event)
```